# How to update an object in a nested array inside another nested array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

In mongo DB I have a collection dealing with buildings ("centros") that contain devices ("dispositivos") and those devices contain sensors ("sensores").
I am trying to update one of those sensors.
Buildings are identified by their "_id", devices by their "uid" and sensors by their "variable name" ("variable").
I have already tried following some examples found on StackOverflow, but have not succeeded.

This is my approximation:

```
db.collection.update({
  "uid": "e898b585-d855-4017-9fe4-0644360f9d1b"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "dispositivos.$[dispositivo].sensores.$[sensor]": {
      "variable": "Plutonio",
      "unidad": "yuyuyuyuuyu"
    }
  }
},
{
  "multi": false,
  "upsert": false,
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "dispositivo.uid": "e898b585-d855-4017-9fe4-064386kkkkkk",
      "sensor.variable": "intensidad"
    }
  ]
})
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
fail to run update: multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{Error parsing array filter :: caused by :: Expected a single top-level field name, found 'sensor' and 'dispositivo'}]}, {<nil>}]
```

There you have a live sample: https://mongoplayground.net/p/KrWw2WxkSch

This is my collection sample:

```
[
  {
    "uid": "e898b585-d855-4017-9fe4-0644360f9d1b",
    "nombre": "Colegio Rio Piles",
    "tipo": "Colegio",
    "direccion": {
      "calle": "Paseo Dr. Fleming, 1109",
      "codigoPostal": "33204",
      "municipio": "Gijon",
      "provincia": "Asturias",
      "ubicacion": {
        "latitud": "43.5351406",
        "longitud": "-5.6345379"
      }
    },
    "horario": {
      "apertura": "09:00",
      "cierre": "22:00"
    },
    "dispositivos": [
      {
        "uid": "e898b585-d855-4017-9fe4-064386055555",
        "descripcion": "",
        "tipo": "ANALIZADOR_RED",
        "adquisicion": "30s",
        "sensores": [
          {
            "variable": "voltaje",
            "unidad": "V"
          },
          {
            "variable": "intensidad",
            "unidad": "A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "uid": "e898b585-d855-4017-9fe4-064386kkkkkk",
        "descripcion": "",
        "tipo": "CONTADOR_AGUA",
        "adquisicion": "30s",
        "sensores": [
          {
            "variable": "caudal",
            "unidad": "l/s"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks JOE for the help. That is the solution:

```
db.collection.update({
  "uid": "e898b585-d855-4017-9fe4-0644360f9d1b"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "dispositivos.$[dispositivo].sensores.$[sensor]": {
      "variable": "Plutonio",
      "unidad": "yuyuyuyuuyu"
    }
  }
},
{
  "multi": false,
  "upsert": false,
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "dispositivo.uid": "e898b585-d855-4017-9fe4-064386055555"
    },
    {
      "sensor.variable": "intensidad"
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each array filter should be its own object in the array, like

```
 arrayFilters: [
    {
      "dispositivo.uid": "e898b585-d855-4017-9fe4-064386kkkkkk"
    },
    {
      "sensor.variable": "intensidad"
    }
  ]
```